# how can I download a file with Zend_Http_Client or other library

Tags: php, zend-framework, download

I am trying to find a solution to get directly the file like **wget** does instead of reading from the stream and writing to another file, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's implementation of CURL?

Comment: I guess cURL has the same approach of writing to a file what it reads from the source. I want to download the file without opening it and recreating its mime type and stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also found [copy](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) which allows to copy a file from an url directly to your disk and is a oneliner without the complexity of curl or the need to create an empty file where to transfer the content of file_get_contents.

```
copy($file_url, $localpath);
```

Comment: you dont have to create an empty file. just provide an writable filepath.

Comment: Did not know about the copy() solution... will do some benchmarking. Sound interesting.

Comment: Benchmarked exec wget, copy() and curl... All have nearly same runtime and memory usage. Edited my answer for later reference. Thanks for your copy()-Solution +1.

Answer (score 1):

With `CURLOPT_FILE` you can write some filestream direct into an open filehandle (see [curl_setopt](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).

```
/**
 * @param string $url
 * @param string $destinationFilePath
 * @throws Exception
 * @return string
 */
protected function _downloadFile($url, $destinationFilePath)
{
    $fileHandle = fopen($destinationFilePath, 'w');

    if (false === $fileHandle) {
        throw new Exception('Could not open filehandle');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fileHandle);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fileHandle);

    if (false === $result) {
        throw new Exception('Could not download file');
    }

    return $destinationFilePath;
}
```

Edit based on your comments:
If you want a oneliner or want to use wget call it through [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) like so:

```
exec('wget http://google.de/ -O google.html -q')
```

Edit for later reference:

```
<?php
function downloadCurl($url, $destinationFilePath)
{
    $fileHandle = fopen($destinationFilePath, 'w');

    if (false === $fileHandle) {
        throw new Exception('Could not open filehandle');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fileHandle);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fileHandle);

    if (false === $result) {
        throw new Exception('Could not download file');
    }
}


function downloadCopy($url, $destinationFilePath)
{
    if (false === copy($url, $destinationFilePath)) {
        throw new Exception('Could not download file');
    }
}

function downloadExecWget($url, $destinationFilePath)
{
    $output = array();
    $return = null;
    exec(sprintf('wget %s -O %s -q', escapeshellarg($url), escapeshellarg($destinationFilePath)), $output, $return);
    
    if (1 === $return) {
        throw new Exception('Could not download file');
    }
}
```

All three methods have nearly equal runtime and memory usage.
Use whatever fits best to your environment.

Comment: the same. I want to download the file not to read it and recreate it.

Comment: Elzo: The file is written directly to a local file. It's the same as wget does.

Comment: not directly. I have to fopen a file and fclose it. no? wget is oneliner.

Comment: You have to open the filehandle to write a new file. The filestream is written directly to the filehandle.

Comment: I know about exec + wget, but I am looking for a strict php solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> file_put_contents($local_path, file_get_contents($file_url));

is a one liner too ;-)

The only issue with above code could be with very large files: copy could be better in that case, but see also http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#88520

Some testing needed...

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/my_file.tar.gz');
```

And now write $c to local file ...

Comment: read my coments. file_get_contents gives me a string that I have to write to a file. I want THE FILE not to create a copy.

Comment: I did not understand "I want the file" ... where in a php variable ? on filesystem ? where ...

Comment: yes, on the file system. there the files stay. what you have in a variable or in memory is not a file